# Electron app slower when running from NAS

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I have an incredibly simple packaged Electron app. All it does is open browser windows on the back of WebSocket events (serve a URL). When running the .exe from a network share location I notice the following:

- the actual app is slower to launch browser windows to a usable state (this is after the app has "warmed up")  - I haven't figured out what this is down to yet (can't launch DevTools)
- can't launch DevTools

If I copy the same binaries to a local location - I don't see these issues. I had a search and couldn't find anything related to this - but is this an explainable issue? Is there anything built into electron that will copy the required bits over locally?

Comment: Interesting question! Can you provide some measurements as to how long the startup takes?

Comment: An extra 1-2 seconds

Comment: I've managed to get devtools to open. There is a 1s pause where it doesn't seem to be doing anything between downloading index.html and loading the remaining resources.

Comment: It sounds like slower disk access than local, and Electron apps aren't exactly small since they bundle the entire Chromium runtime. Does the delay also appear when you close and reopen the app? Maybe the filesystem cache will alleviate some of this.

Comment: The app opens windows on the back of websocket events, every window has the same delay